# Is there any way to open instagram camera page from webapp on Android?

Tags: android, html, web-applications, instagram

I'm trying to open the instagram camera page from HTML on Android devices.

Here is the code that works well for IOS but doesn't work for Android devices:

`<a href="Instagram://camera"> Open Instagram </a>`.

Opening the instagarm app on any other page(not on the camera page) is accepted as a fallback solution, but the only way that i found is to use:

`<href="http://instagram.com/p/"> Open Instagram </a>`

Which results in an error("Couldn't refresh feed"), because the url is missing the picture id.